# Answer has automatically become community wiki

Tags: support

I have [an answer](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/9321/102) that I've been working away at and updating as I found out more and more information (or fixed typos). There was a fair bit of effort involved experimenting with different values and finding links etc...

Now I see that it has automatically changed into a community wiki answer. This is a bit gutting, as I think I was the only person contributing to it. I'm all for contributing to the community and sharing answers, but it doesn't really make sense in this case.

Can this be reverted?

Comment: You did make alot of edits :)

Comment: @DanielBlackhall, Yes. Yes I Did. :) In my defense, the results didn't really line up with what I expected from the online Salesforce docs. I needed to experiment a bit to see how close the overlap with Java was. That, and I can't spell very well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like it got marked as such due to the high number of edits... I've just reverted it and it says that it should prevent the same from happening again to this answer.

Comment: Many thanks. I'll try to do better with my spelling and grammar so I don't need so many edits in the future.

Comment: To be honest I'm surprised I've never activated that myself — I often make multiple edits after posting!

Comment: I think a warning is given that this may happen if you edit a few times, that is usually the point where I stop editing.

Comment: @Sdry Never be afraid to improve an answer. These automated process work the vast majority of the time, but when they miss the mark, the problem is easily fixed. That's why moderators are often called *exception handlers.*

Answer (score 5):

Going forward, there will be no need to revert, because a similarly edited answer will not get auto converted.

It was just announced in [their latest blog post](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/04/putting-the-community-back-in-wiki/) that the Stack Exchange has removed all automatic Wiki conversion triggers:

> No longer will answers with more than some arbitrary number of edits, or questions with more than a page of answers suddenly lose their owners. To handle those rare situations where unusual activity levels may indicate misuse, we’ve added some new moderator flags in these scenarios: they can respond when necessary by closing or locking the post – but when there is no fire behind the smoke, they can silently dismiss the flag without disruption.

**It was a system that converted helpfulness and generosity into a slap in the face – from a robot.**
[image: robot slaps human in face]